# Does the centralizer of the identity component map onto the component group?

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a Lie group, $G_0$ the connected component of the identity, $\pi:G\to G/G_0$ the quotient map onto the component group, and $C_G(G_0)$ the centralizer of $G_0$ in $G$.

Question: Is it always the case that $\pi(C_G(G_0))=G/G_0$? If not, is there a "nice" non-trivial (e.g., not just the connected ones) class of Lie groups $G$ always having this property?

I suspect this is false in general, but there seem to be many natural examples where this occurs, such as in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$, which has the stronger property that $Z(G)$ maps onto $G/G_0$, or in the product of a connected Lie group with a discrete group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the centralizer need not map surjectively onto the component group.

One family of counterexamples is proved by the Lie groups $O(2n) = \{A\in M_{2n}(\mathbb{R}): AA^t = A^tA = I\}$, which has the identity component  $SO(2n) = \{A\in O(2n): \det(A) = 1\}$.

Given any $A\in SO(2n)$ and any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, $B$ permutes the $\lambda$-eigenspaces of $A$:  if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $$\lambda (Bv) = B\lambda v = BAv = A(Bv).$$

For most $A$, these eigenspaces are $1$-dimensional, which implies that $B$ acts as $\pm 1$ on each one.  Doing this for all $A$ easily implies that every vector is an eigenvector for $B$, so $B = \pm I$.

But since $2n$ is even, $\det(\pm I) = 1$, so this means $B\in SO(2n)$.  That is, $C_{O(2n)}(SO(2n))\subseteq SO(2n)$.

Comment: I don't know of a nice non-trivial class of spaces where the centralizers map surjectively onto the component group.  To my thinking, compact Lie groups are among the nicest topological groups, and counterexamples appear the moment you get more than one component.

Comment: Perhaps "nice" was the wrong word, I was thinking more like "natural". For example, I was thinking something like (non-compact) semisimple, but in any case, I appreciate this clear counterexample.

Comment: @IianSmythe:  I think if you take my example and product it with $\mathbb{R}$, you get a non-compact semi-simple example.  I wasn't try to judge your selection of the word "nice".  Perhaps another way to phrase my comment is that apart from "connected", I don't know of a reasonable adjective to add which guarantees the centralizer maps to onto the component group.